# Does a .NET Web Service instantiate with each method call?

Tags: .net, web-services

I'm trying out web services for an idea I've had.
Running in debug it looks like the web service class instantiates each time a client calls a method in the web service.  I can see this by seeing that the constructor gets called each time I call a method.
I only instantiate the proxy web service once in the client.

This would mean I would have to store all data between calls and means that if I use a databse I'll have to re-connect with for every call to a method.

That can't be correct?

Comment: Why? That's how web pages work and a web service is really just a web page with an alternative function.

Comment: Oh right.  Like a web page.  Bother!
I'll try the WCF idea
Thanks

Comment: Spencer Ruport: If you haven't dealt with web pages or other stateless frameworks before, it will seem strange at first. After all, in a stateful frameworks you will not have to do all that extra work multiple times.

Comment: Even if you go WCF, you really should do your best to avoid state.  Remember, in a distributed system, you should expect any machine to be disconnected or rebooted at any time.  If the server maintains state, it becomes a weak point.  Aside from stability, it also affects scalability, because clusters would need to share that state.

Comment: I'm thinking of a service that delivers info (a single number)to who ever accesses the web service.  Having to remake the database connection for each request seems like a huge overhead.  Can I get round that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For ASMX, it's correct and largely a good thing.  Services should be as stateless as possible, and if you really need to store something between calls then you can use a singleton.  I don't think holding onto a database connection would qualify, though, because they're cached and you want to scope your use, anyhow.

If you want a single object to stay alive between calls, WCF does offer this option.  Given that ASMX is obsolete, you might want to move to WCF.

Comment: Maybe not quite obsolete. "Legacy" is the word MS uses.

Answer (score 5):

That is indeed correct.

Web Services (in a Service Oriented Architecture) are meant to be stateless (they don't remember anything between calls...all data persistance is up to you).

If you search long enough on the web, you'll find attempts to create stateful web services (which do have their place, but go against the core principals of SOA). You'll find, though, that they don't alleviate your concerns. You'll get a new class instantianciation with every call and any connections to the DB will have to be re-created.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's 100% correct. Every time a request is received by the server, a new object is instantiated to handle the request on a separate thread.

This is the same thing that happens with a basic ASP.NET Web Form.